# Setting slider widtth to auto in JS CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've a problem with my slider, the width in JS is set to 1366, but I'm trying to change it to auto but it wouldn't work. how can I achieve that? the problem that when the site is opened on wide screens, the width matches it and everything is great except the slider, it doesn't resize

```js
effectsDemo2 = 'rain,stairs,fade';
var demoSlider_2 = Sliderman.slider({
  container: 'SliderName_2',
  width: 1366,
  height: 630,
  effects: effectsDemo2,
  display: {
    autoplay: 3000,
    loading: {
      background: '#000000',
      opacity: 0.5,
      image: 'img/loading.gif'
    },
    buttons: {
      hide: true,
      opacity: 1,
      prev: {
        className: 'SliderNamePrev_2',
        label: ''
      },
      next: {
        className: 'SliderNameNext_2',
        label: ''
      }
    },
    description: {
      hide: true,
      background: '#000000',
      opacity: 0.4,
      height: 50,
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    navigation: {
      container: 'SliderNameNavigation_2',
      label: '<img src="img/clear.gif" />'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="SliderName_2" class="SliderName_2">
  <img src="img/1.jpg" usemap="#img1map" />
  <map name="img1map">
      <area href="#img1map-area1" shape="rect" coords="100,100,200,200" />
      <area href="#img1map-area2" shape="rect" coords="300,100,400,200" />
     </map>
  <div class="SliderName_2Description"></div>
  <img src="img/2.jpg" />
  <div class="SliderName_2Description"></div>
  <img src="img/3.jpg" />
  <div class="SliderName_2Description"></div>
  <img src="img/4.jpg" />
  <div class="SliderName_2Description"></div>
</div>
<div class="c"></div>
<div id="SliderNameNavigation_2"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
```

Comment: Without a functional demonstration showing which slideshow plugin you're using and all the relevant CSS and images, we can't help. I'd suggest reading the slider plugin's documentation to see how to implement the slider responsively.

Comment: try to put it on a container and set the container to xx% width , inside that container set the width of your slider to 100%

Comment: That's the slider I'm using http://www.devtrix.net/sliderman/

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin you are using for the slider support width value as '100%', you can pass this value and wrap your slider in another HTML element. Then apply CSS on the HTML element and use media query to scale accordingly to viewports width.

The following code is not tested but should work for your problem

HTML

```
<div class="sliderWrapper">
     ... Your slider code
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sliderWrapper {
    width: 350px
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
   .sliderWrapper {
       width: 700px
  }
}
```